# Getting encrypted password in request body

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have recorded one script in JMeter but while recording the script I entered login credentials with proper values.

But after completed script creation,  getting the encrypted password in the request body of that request.

Below is the request body ( The request is in post method):

[image]

```
{"program":"AuthService","data":{"email":"saisruthi.chinta@petronas.com","password":"U2FsdGVkX1/FzXRlpSCnRB+FqsAcDF8+7FonOIS5eZo=","apiContextCode":"petronas"}}
```

If provided the variable here in place of password value to pass data from CSV it is failing because of the encrypted password.

Answer (score 0):

Your password seems to be salt encoded before sending it to the server. It is hard to tell how it's been encoded.

1. You need to take a look the js resouce file which is responsible for the encoding.
2. take a look at the network tab in the developer tools and identify the js resource file responsible for encoding
3. Try to replicate the same logic using JSR223 pre-processor to encode the password before passing it in the request.
4. If you are not able to identify the js/encryption methodology - you can reach to your dev team for help

Comment: gist.github.com/mateuszwrobel/368976797ec5b9d86944 This logic were used for encryption purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It's at least [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded

[image]

with regards to what else - you need to look into your page source and look for the funcition responsible for the encryption. Once done you will be able to re-implement the encryption code using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). Take a look at [Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mateuszwrobel/368976797ec5b9d86944


This logic were used for encryption purpose.